# Modify magento 1.9 main menu html code

Tags: php, html, magento-1.9

I have a problem with main navigation menu in Magento 1.9:

```
 <nav class="navbar" role="navigation"> <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li  class="dropdown"><a href="#"  class="level-top dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">AAA<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu"><li class="title"><a href="#">AAB</a>
  <li class="" data-submenu-id="submenu-category-node-13550"><a href="#" class=" has-submenu" >AAE</a>
    <div id="submenu-category-node-13550" class="popover">
       <h2>CHANGE TAG! </h2> 
       <ul> <li  class=""><a href="...
```

I would like to change the tag H2 inside the submenu, in an H3 tag or other tag, but I don't know where I can find the code; I try to search in app/code/core/Mage/Catolg/Block/Navigation.php and also in efault\template\page\html\header.phtml but without success...

Can anyone helps me? Thanks!

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49068/how-to-use-custom-navigation-menu-instead-of-categories-menu

Answer (score 0):

The code shows that this is not exactly the standard menu of the Magento, so look in these folders

```
app\code\community\
app\code\local\
```

you may have a module like MegaMenu installed. Therefore, you need to search the file in the module.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrey! I find the solution in app\code\local\...block\topmenu.php you was right!